# Custom title vs. Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set a custom title on my activity (using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);`), with a custom title height. I have my custom style and theme all set up. Everything works fine as long as my theme inherits from `android:Theme`. It gets the custom background, custom titlebar height, all as expected. However, if my custom theme inherits from `android:Theme.Dialog` then it refuses to honor my custom titlebar height. It is just stuck at about 25px or so. (Which is weird, since before putting in any custom title stuff, the default titlebar was about 50px or so).

Is there any way to set a custom title on a Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u create custom dialog instead.
Hope this can help

```
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);//this will get the custom dialgo layout
            dialog.setTitle("Here is your custom title");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            //custom dialog has been created. Time to show
            dialog.show()
```

Comment: Well, I only have two activities in my application. Neither of them have need of OK or Cancel buttons in any form. One is a ListActivity, which responds to the CREATE_SHORTCUT intent, and one is an activity where the whole layout is simply a GridView. They are very simple activities with no need of all the extraneous Dialog functionality, I'm just trying to emulate that look. I think i am on to something though, with a theme that will extened `android:Theme` and simply add to it the Dialog attributes (such as floating).